# Hoffstein–Lockhart for non-congruence subgroups

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $\Gamma$ be a non-congruence subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of finite index and let $f$ be a holomorphic cuspidal modular form of weight $k$ for the group $\Gamma$. For simplicity, assume that $\Gamma_\infty \subset \Gamma$ and that $f$ has the Fourier expansion given by
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) e^{2\pi i nz}.
$$

I am interested in the trivial lower bounds for $L(1, \mbox{Sym}^2 f)$ (in the spirit of Hoffstein–Lockhart) where

$$
L(s, \mbox{Sym}^2 f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k(n)|^2}{n^s}.
$$

The situation is increasingly complicated as compared to the congruent subgroup case. For example, a conjecture of Atkin (resolved by Berger?) asserts that the Hecke operators on $\Gamma$ (defined using double cosets for example) are not interesting and they act trivially on modular forms which are purely non congruent (that is not a modular form for any congruence subgroup). Therefore, the Fourier coefficients of these modular forms need not be multiplicative and need not satisfy the Hecke relations. As a consequence, $L(s,\mbox{Sym}^2 f)$ need not have an Euler product. This prevents us from generalizing the argument for the congruence case as given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181123/holomorphic-hoffstein-lockhart).

Is there any other lower bound (in terms of the weight $k$) available in literature?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think any lower bound is available, and I wouldn't expect it to be possible to prove a useful bound using current methods.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Do we have any conjectural bound?

Comment: The naive guess would be the same as in the congruence case, but no one has thought about this.

Comment: But even for the "trivial" bound to hold, don't we require there to be an Euler Product for the L series in question?

Comment: @PeterHumphries For $k$ even $\ge 4$ I think there is a trivial bound for the Petersson norm of the Poincare series $P_{k,\Gamma}(z) = \sum_{\gamma\in T\backslash\Gamma} \gamma'(z)^{k/2} e^{2i\pi \gamma(z)}\in S_k(\Gamma)$ from the sup norm of $|\alpha'(x+i/2)^{-k/2} P_{k,\Gamma\alpha}(x+i/2)|$ for each $\alpha\in SL_2(Z)/\Gamma$ which gives something like $|P_{k,\Gamma \alpha}(z)|\le  |e^\pi e^{2i\pi z}| \sum_{c,d\in \Bbb{Z}^2-(0,0)}|ci/2+d|^{-4}$. As $a_1(f)(4\pi)^{1-k}(k-1)!=\langle f,P_{k,\Gamma}\rangle$ it gives a lower bound for $\|f\|^2/|a_1(f)|^2$.